# FireBase Messaging fails to load admin_sdk.properties in OSGI bundle

Tags: java, maven, firebase-cloud-messaging, osgi, firebase-admin

I am using Firebase-admin:7.1.0 to send push notifications through my server (WSO2IS). Java version is adopt 8.0.275.

I have followed the doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#java for the setup. JSON file exists, the env variable is exported, FireBase is initialized using:

```
FirebaseOptions options =
          FirebaseOptions.builder()
              .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault())
              .build();
      FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

When trying to send a push notification using:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Failed to load: admin_sdk.properties
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:910)
    at com.google.firebase.internal.SdkUtils.loadSdkVersion(SdkUtils.java:46)
    at com.google.firebase.internal.SdkUtils.<clinit>(SdkUtils.java:31)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.<clinit>(FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.java:65)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$6.get(FirebaseMessaging.java:414)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$6.get(FirebaseMessaging.java:411)
    at com.google.common.base.Suppliers$NonSerializableMemoizingSupplier.get(Suppliers.java:167)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.getMessagingClient(FirebaseMessaging.java:296)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.sendOp(FirebaseMessaging.java:131)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.send(FirebaseMessaging.java:102)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.send(FirebaseMessaging.java:86)
```

Couldn't find anything about this failure. Any ideas?

EDIT:
First of all, this is integrated into an OSGI bundle using apache felix plugin for maven. Most probably, the configuration of the pom.xml file is the culprit..

Some info about the pom.xml bellow:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

...

<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <obrRepository>NONE</obrRepository>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Name>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
                     <Axis2Module>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</Axis2Module>
                        <Import-Package>                           
                            com.google.firebase.*,
                            com.google.api.*,
                            com.google.auth.*,
                            *;resolution:=optional
                        </Import-Package>
                        <Export-Package>                           
                            com.google.firebase.*,
                            com.google.api.*,
                            com.google.auth.*;                        
                        </Export-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>manifest</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

EDIT #2:

The dependency jar for firebase is firebase-admin-7.1.0.jar which contains the package com.google.firebase, the META-INF folder and the admin_sdk.properties file. Of course, when I export the packages com.google.whatever the properties file is not exported with the bundle and this is the reason behind the exception.

So, question is, how do I make sure that the properties file is included in the bundle?

Answer (score 0):

You can always add the whole jar in question to your OSGI bundle in such cases.

```
Embed-Dependency
```

tag can be used in the configuration tag of the bundle of felix.

Final form:

```
<bundle>
   <configuration>
      <import / export etc>...
      <Embed-Dependency>
          firebase-admin;scope=compile|runtime
      </Embed-Dependency>
   </configuration>
</bundle>
```